# How to GET session in function createWebSocketInbound () when programming websocket using Tomcat

Tags: session, tomcat, websocket

As is known, function createWebSocketInbound( String subprotocol, HttpServletRequest request) has 2 parameters.

But when i use this function, i cannot get session with user information which i put in when logining from parameter "request". Instead, when i use request.getSession(), i get a new session with nothing in it... What can i do to get user login info in request or how can i pass my login info into this function?

My Code:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "/websocket"})
public class WebSocketWebSocketServlet extends WebSocketServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private AdminBean chatter;  //Login information

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    Object obj = request.getAttribute("admin");  //obj turns out to be null ...
    super.doGet(request, response);
}

@Override
protected StreamInbound createWebSocketInbound(String subProtocol,HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println("Create a new Instance of WebSocketServlet");
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    this.chatter = (AdminBean) session.getAttribute("LoginUser"); //chatter turns out to be null ...
    Object obj = request.getAttribute("admin");  //obj turns out to be null ...
    return new WebSocketMessageInbound(chatter);
}
```

}